# Why does this vba sentence go wrong? If Cells(i, 1).Value = "M" Then

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub a()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 8
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "M" Then
    Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "go wrong" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the sheet information along with the cells.

Example: `Sheet1.Cells(i,1).Value` or `Worksheets("Sheet name").Cells(i,1).Value`

Comment: Although that is good practice, if sheet information is not included, it will just default to ActiveSheet. Whether that's his problem depends on what he means by "go wrong"